# Redirect issue with HTML.BeginForm MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following concern (maybe looking for a different way to do this).  I have a form that I send to a post controller that returns void.  My form uses the following format:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm", area = "MyArea" }))
```

I really need those parameters in place for all other things to work, but the problem is that after my form submits, it tries to redirect to that controller/action, and since it's a void action, I get a blank page.  I have some javascript I use for the onclick event of the submit button which holds where I want to redirect to:

```
onclick='var promise = Dialog("Confirm:", "Are you sure you wan to proceed? ","", "frm"); 
                  promise.fail(function () 
                      {successfulSave("Error!", "There was a problem processing your request");});
                promise.done(function () 
{ $("#frm").submit(); successfulSave("Success!", "Locale Saved Successfully"); 
       setTimeout(function() {window.location.href="@Url.Action("Action2", "Controller", new {area = "MyArea"})";}, 3000);});'
```

I want to redirect to Controller2/Action2...not the post action the form holds (Controller/Action) and perform the checks in the onclick event (successfulDialog).

Comment: Why not set the return type from being `void` to being `ActionResult` and just send it back to your Index() or something (using `return RedirectToAction("Index");`)

Comment: I thought about this, however, if I do it that way, I cannot post a bootstrap modal (my successfulSave function)

Comment: Are you trying to achieve AJAX-like functionality?

Comment: More or less, except I don't think the ajax form takes in the parameters I'm passing does it? This method does exactly what I want, except that it's redirecting to the incorrect action

Comment: Yes, you can send parameters to the AjaxForm.  If it were me, I would simply create some jQuery to create an AJAX request then change your method from `void` to `JsonResult` and then it would be a true AJAX request.  MVC's ajax stuff works, too, but there's a slight learning curve.  I don't think you can do what you're trying to do with a simple form; this will require AJAX someway or another.

Comment: If I decide to go the ajax route...can I still (somehow) send the javascript calls I'm doing? I just don't see how I would accomplish that if I use Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: I'd keep `@Html.BeginForm()` and learn to do AJAX the jquery way. That method will work with non-MS tech and you'll find a whole lot more resources to help you.

Comment: So, I would have to pass empty strings for the Controller/Action and just handle the onclick correct?

Answer (score 2):

"I want to redirect to Controller2/Action2...not the post action the form holds (Controller/Action)."

If I understand this statement, you want to post to Controller/Action, and then redirect to Controller2/Action2.  To do this you return RedirectToAction from the post action.

```
public ActionResult Action(MyViewModel vm)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //do whatever, save to database
      return RedirectToAction("Action2", "Controller");
   }

   //error
   return View();
}
```

Comment: I want to display or accomplish the stuff done under the onclick event though.  Show the successfulSave message

Comment: So you are going to show them the success message for 3 seconds and then do the redirect?

Comment: Then I agree with others.  I would wire to the form submit event, preventdefault to keep the default submit behavior from occurring, and  use a $.ajax so you can handle the success event.  Ajax.BeginForm has a success event but I think you will find all of its default behaviors will interfere with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, if I have no other choice then I will do it. It's probably the best way to go. I'll show the confirm on the beforeSend, and on afterSuccess I'll just include the redirect, and on success the dialog successfulSave. I appreciate your help :)